# Nginx reverse proxy to Poste.io

Tags: nginx, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I have a VPS has running some services and Nginx reversing proxy between that's

I want to running Poste.io on this server but got bad gateway

Nginx config file like that:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name mail.domain.com;

    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    proxy_set_header Host               $host;
    proxy_set_header Connection         "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Upgrade            $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port   $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host   $host:$server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;  
   
    location / {
        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:1443/;
        # proxy_redirect default;
    }

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mail.domain.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

docker compose like that:

```
version: "3"

services:
  poste.io:
    image: analogic/poste.io:latest
    hostname: mail.domain.com
    environment:
      - VIRTUAL_HOST=mail.domain.com
      - HTTPS=OFF
    ports:
      - "1080:80"  # HTTP
      - "1443:443" # HTTPS
```

Answer (score 0):

replace proxy pass with `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1080/;`

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.